# Error when using Ocelot Kubernetes Provider 17.0.0 Error Code: UnableToFindServiceDiscoveryProviderError

Tags: kubernetes, ocelot

Hello I receive this error when running a request through my ocelot api gateway to a down stream service

404 error

Here is my routing file. I have followed the Ocelot Kubernetes docs as well as I could.

```
"{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/home",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/test",
      "ServiceName": "productshttpaggegator",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
    },
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/products/{postId}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/products/{postId}",
      "ServiceName": "productshttpaggegator",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "Get" ]
    }
  ],
        "GlobalConfiguration": {
          "ServiceDiscoveryProvider": {
      
            "Type": "KubernetesServiceDiscoveryProvider"

          }
        }

}"
```

Comment: do I need to setup an RBAC cluster role? Token? Host? Port?